# Continuous progression of a variable (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a continous counter. I mean, I want to close the page and in the other day open it and continue the counter from where I left.

Like, my counter did count 14235 times in one day. In another day I want it to continue from where I left (14235).

Code I made :

```
var a = 0; //// a is the "counter"
function count() { ///// function to count

  chrome.storage.local.get(['a'], function(value) { return a = value.a;});
  a += 1;

  chrome.storage.local.set({"a": a}, function(){})  
  console.log(a)

  setTimeout(count, 5000)
}

count()
```

I get 2 values in console.log, one from 0 and one from 14235, while I want get only one. Help.

Comment: none seems know what to do D:

Comment: At a guess, I might suggest you consider that chrome.storage.local.get() and chrome.storage.local.set() are asynchronous. You may be adding to the value before the get() has actually set the value of a.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not getting well seen so I decided help you.
You cannot make **a** equal the last value, at least I cannot do it.

But you can do a better thing. Call it.

```
function count() {
  if(a === 0){ chrome.storage.local.get(['b'], function(value) { return a = value.b  }); } else { chrome.storage.local.set({"b": a}, function(){})  }   
    /// here, if a = 0 it will get the previous value but if a != 0 it will save the value :D

  console.log(a)    
  setTimeout(count, 100)
  a += 1;
}

count()
```

Hope see you again !

Comment: @H. romeo thanks :D, that did work perfectly. You seems a nice guy and also very smart. Hope see you again :DD